# Flutter app run error : Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

When I try to run my flutter project I get this error.

**Fluter app run error : Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'**

Debug:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                ^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

My main.dart file looks like this :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: kTextColor),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Update** :
Running **flutter pub get** in pubspec.yaml doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This is your error
:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null

Comment: It says it's in the source folder in flutter. I don't think I can edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add the following dependency or last version

> flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3

2. Run `flutter pub get` command